# Unresolved attribute reference 'transaction' for class 'Pool' Asyncpg

Tags: python, база-данных, aiogram, asyncpg

Пытаюсь обернуть несколько запросов бд в транзакцию, но получаю ошибку.
Весь код:

```
class DbSession(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, connector: asyncpg.pool.Pool):
        super().__init__()
        self.connector = connector

    async def __call__(
            self,
            handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
            event: TelegramObject,
            data: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> Any:
        async with self.connector.acquire() as connect:
            data['request'] = Request(connect)
            return await handler(event, data)


class Request:
    def __init__(self, connector: asyncpg.pool.Pool):
        self.connector = connector

    async def function(self):
        async with self.connection.transaction():  # Ошибка
            (запросы)

async def create_pool():
    return await asyncpg.create_pool(user='postgres', database='csbotdata',
                                 host='localhost', port='5432',
                                 password='123')


async def main():
    dp.update.middleware.register(DbSession(await create_pool()))
```